# How I can continue training from checkpoint keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I train the first checkpoint model on 2 epoch with the following code :

```
def check_units(y_true, y_pred):
if y_pred.shape[1] != 1:
    y_pred = y_pred[:,1:2]
    y_true = y_true[:,1:2]
return y_true, y_pred

def precision(y_true, y_pred):
y_true, y_pred = check_units(y_true, y_pred)
true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
return precision

def recall(y_true, y_pred):
y_true, y_pred = check_units(y_true, y_pred)
true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
return recall

def fmeasure(y_true, y_pred):
def recall(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall

def precision(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision

y_true, y_pred = check_units(y_true, y_pred)
precision = precision(y_true, y_pred)
recall = recall(y_true, y_pred)
return 2 * ((precision * recall) / (precision + recall + K.epsilon()))

classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(6, (3, 3), input_shape = (30, 30, 3), data_format="channels_last", activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(6, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

opt = Adam(learning_rate = 0.001, beta_1 = 0.9, beta_2 = 0.999, epsilon = 1e-08, decay = 0.0)
classifier.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy', precision, recall, fmeasure])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               horizontal_flip = True,
                               vertical_flip = True,
                               rotation_range = 180)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/dataset/training_set',
                                             target_size = (30, 30),
                                             batch_size = 32,
                                             class_mode = 'binary')

validation_set = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/dataset/validation_set',
                                                    target_size = (30, 30),
                                                    batch_size = 32,
                                                    class_mode = 'binary')

history = classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                               steps_per_epoch = 208170,
                               epochs = 2,
                               validation_data = validation_set,
                               validation_steps = 89140)

classifier.save('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Checkpoints/Checkpoint_1/Model.h5')
```

To continue training (the seconde checkpoint model) from the first checkpoint model I use  this code :

```
def check_units(y_true, y_pred):
if y_pred.shape[1] != 1:
    y_pred = y_pred[:,1:2]
    y_true = y_true[:,1:2]
return y_true, y_pred

def precision(y_true, y_pred):
y_true, y_pred = check_units(y_true, y_pred)
true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
return precision

def recall(y_true, y_pred):
y_true, y_pred = check_units(y_true, y_pred)
true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
return recall

def fmeasure(y_true, y_pred):
def recall(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall

def precision(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision

y_true, y_pred = check_units(y_true, y_pred)
precision = precision(y_true, y_pred)
recall = recall(y_true, y_pred)
return 2 * ((precision * recall) / (precision + recall + K.epsilon()))

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               horizontal_flip = True,
                               vertical_flip = True,
                               rotation_range = 180)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/dataset/training_set',
                                             target_size = (30, 30),
                                             batch_size = 32,
                                             class_mode = 'binary')

validation_set = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/dataset/validation_set',
                                                    target_size = (30, 30),
                                                    batch_size = 32,
                                                    class_mode = 'binary')

custom_metrics = {
'precision' : precision,
'recall' : recall,
'fmeasure' : fmeasure    
}

classifier = load_model('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Checkpoints/Checkpoint_1/Model.h5', custom_objects = custom_metrics)

history = classifier.fit(training_set,
                     steps_per_epoch = 208170,
                     epochs = 2,
                     validation_data = validation_set,
                     validation_steps = 89140)

classifier.save('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Checkpoints/Checkpoint_2/Model.h5')
```

But I got this error why ?

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 416340 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 89140 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
```

Comment: These are warnings, not errors

Comment: Yes but the training stopped after it show this warnings

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your steps per epoch was too large a value, try using an expression instead of a numerical input that reduces the dimension.

`steps_per_epoch = len(input_train)//BATCH_SIZE`

Might as well try this, considering the dataset and input size the above expression should help you start training.

Comment: But if I use this expression len(input_train)//BATCH_SIZE then the model was trained on less number of examples not on my total number 208170 ?

Comment: steps_per_epoch: Total number of steps (batches of samples) to yield from generator before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next epoch. It should typically be equal to the number of unique samples of your dataset divided by the batch size.

So, no your data isn't trained on less number of examples.

Answer (score 0):

From what I found in your code above, you create your both your training and testing datasets using the code below.

```py
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/dataset/training_set',
                                             target_size = (30, 30),
                                             batch_size = 32,
                                             class_mode = 'binary')

validation_set = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/dataset/validation_set',
                                                    target_size = (30, 30),
                                                    batch_size = 32,
                                                    class_mode = 'binary')
```

An easy fix if you are using Tensorflow 1.X is to something similar to what Manik was talking about. Adjust your fit function to take the following formula, `int(steps_per_epoch/batch_size)`.

```py
history = classifier.fit(training_set,
                     steps_per_epoch = int(208170/batch_size),
                     epochs = 2,
                     validation_data = validation_set,
                     validation_steps = int(89140/batch_size))
```

If you are using Tensorflow 2.X+, then the following function would better suit what you are looking for. The answer of which I found at this Github issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25254

```py
#Get your data
training_set...
validation_set...

#Declare the types and shape of your data
types = (tf.float32, tf.int32)
shapes = ((512, 512, 3), (2,))
ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: training_set, types, shapes).shuffle(steps_per_epoch).batch(batch_size)
ds_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: validation_set, types, shapes).shuffle(steps_per_epoch).batch(batch_size)

# usage in model
model.fit(training_set, validation_data=validation_set, epochs=10, verbose=True, callbacks=[visualize, tensorboard])
```